# Why is the resolution of output of this metapost file very bad?

Tags: metapost

I have a MetaPost file which gives an output as EPS. When I convert the EPS file to a PDF, the resolution is very poor. Does any one know how to fix this?

Here is the code of the file:

```
prologues:=3;
outputtemplate:="%j.eps";
verbatimtex
%&latex
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{times}
  \begin{document}
etex
  beginfig(0);
  drawarrow (0,0)--(10cm,0);
  drawarrow (0,0)--(0,10cm);
  label.lrt(btex\small$y$ etex, (0cm,6.4cm));
  label.lrt(btex\small$x$ etex, (8.4cm,0cm)); 
    pair A, B, C;
    A:=(0,0); C:=(4cm,3cm);
    draw A--C;
draw (4cm,3cm) .. (6cm,3.6cm) .. (8cm,3.62cm);
  drawarrow (2cm, 0cm)--(2cm,1cm);
  drawarrow (4cm, 0cm)--(4cm,1cm);
  label.lrt(btex\tiny$x^{m}$ etex, (0.2cm,2.2cm));
  label.lrt(btex\tiny$const-R^{-n}$ etex, (4.6cm,4.4cm));
  label.lrt(btex\tiny$\Delta_{1}$ etex, (2cm,0.2cm));
  label.lrt(btex\tiny$\Delta_{2}$ etex, (4cm,0.2cm));
  label.lrt(btex\tiny$\Delta v$ etex, (6cm,0.2cm));
drawarrow (6cm, 0cm)--(6cm,1cm);
endfig;
end
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How do you do the conversion to PDF?

Comment: through some website.

Comment: What operating system and TeX distribution are you running? Do you need the PDF for inclusion in a LaTeX document?

Comment: I am using Mac. Yes, I need pdf for inclusion in LaTex document.

Comment: You are aware that metapost output can be included directly in latex? Both standard latex and pdflatex, no need for any conversion

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert to PDF via unknown software. It's very easy if you know how to use the Terminal.

Change the `outputtemplate` line into

```
outputtemplate:="%j.mps";
```

and also `\usepackage{times}` into

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

if you want Times also for math symbols.

If you run the command line `mpost titanium` (assuming `titanium.mp`) is the file name, you can then include directly it in a LaTeX file by doing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{titanium}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to obtain a PDF file from the MetaPost file, remove the `outputtemplate` line and run the command line

```
mptopdf titanium.mp
```

that will produce a file named `titanium-0.pdf`, which you can rename to your likings.